# How to avoid the need to delay event emission to the next tick of the event loop?

Tags: node.js, events, event-handling, race-condition, event-loop

I'm writing a Node.js application using a global event emitter. In other words, my application is built entirely around events. I find this kind of architecture working extremely well for me, with the exception of one side case which I will describe here.

Note that I do not think knowledge of Node.js is required to answer this question. Therefore I will try to keep it abstract.

Imagine the following situation:

- A global event emitter (called `mediator`) allows individual modules to listen for application-wide events.
- A HTTP Server is created, accepting incoming requests.
- For each incoming request, an event emitter is created to deal with events specific to this request

An example (purely to illustrate this question) of an incoming request:

```
mediator.on('http.request', request, response, emitter) {

    //deal with the new request here, e.g.:
    response.send("Hello World.");

});
```

So far, so good. One can now extend this application by identifying the requested URL and emitting appropriate events:

```
mediator.on('http.request', request, response, emitter) {

    //identify the requested URL
    if (request.url === '/') {
        emitter.emit('root');
    }
    else {
        emitter.emit('404');
    }

});
```

Following this one can write a module that will deal with a root request.

```
mediator.on('http.request', function(request, response, emitter) {

    //when root is requested
    emitter.once('root', function() {

        response.send('Welcome to the frontpage.');

    });

});
```

Seems fine, right? Actually, it is **potentially broken** code. The reason is that the line `emitter.emit('root')` may be executed before the line `emitter.once('root', ...)`. The result is that the listener never gets executed.

One could deal with this specific situation by delaying the emission of the `root` event to the end of the event loop:

```
mediator.on('http.request', request, response, emitter) {

    //identify the requested URL
    if (request.url === '/') {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            emitter.emit('root');
        });
    }
    else {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            emitter.emit('404');
        });
    }

});
```

The reason this works is because the emission is now delayed until the current event loop has finished, and therefore all listeners have been registered.

However, there are many issues with this approach:

1. one of the advantages of such event based architecture is that emitting modules do not need to know who is listening to their events. Therefore it should not be necessary to decide whether the event emission needs to be delayed, because one cannot know what is going to listen for the event and if it needs it to be delayed or not.
2. it significantly clutters and complexifies code (compare the two examples)
3. it probably worsens performance

As a consequence, my question is: how does one avoid the need to delay event emission to the next tick of the event loop, such as in the described situation?

**Update 19-01-2013**

An example illustrating why this behavior is useful: to allow a http request to be handled in parallel.

```
mediator.on('http.request', function(req, res) {

    req.onceall('json.parsed', 'validated', 'methodoverridden', 'authenticated', function() {
        //the request has now been validated, parsed as JSON, the kind of HTTP method has been overridden when requested to and it has been authenticated
   });

});
```

If each event like `json.parsed` would emit the original request, then the above is not possible because each event is related to another request and you cannot listen for a combination of actions executed in parallel for a specific request.

Comment: Please do tell if anything needs to be elaborated on further.

Comment: Set up all events at start time. Don't attach events (flow control ones) after the application starts. Don't attach events at run time for each request.

Answer (score 3):

Having both a `mediator` which listens for events and an `emitter` which also listens and triggers events seems overly complicated. I'm sure there is a legit reason but my suggestion is to simplify. We use a global `eventBus` in our nodejs service that does something similar. For this situation, I would emit a new event.

```
bus.on('http:request', function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/')
    bus.emit('ns:root', req, res);
  else
    bus.emit('404');
});

// note the use of namespace here to target specific subsystem
bus.once('ns:root', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to the frontpage.');
});
```

Comment: I used this approach until now. The reason I want to start using an inner emitter for each request is because this makes it much easier to take care of events for each single request. For example, all code that handles requests could perform cleanup by doing `emitter.once('timeout', cleanup)` rather than `mediator.on('http.request.timeout', cleanupRequest)`. This may not seem like a big difference, but it is because in the second case the local scope to request in question is lost. I think I would need another huge post with code to explain this properly.

Comment: please see my updated original question for an example on why your approach is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're starting to run into some of the disadvantages of the observer pattern (as mentioned in many books/articles that describe this pattern). My solution is not ideal – assuming an ideal one exists – but:

If you can make a simplifying assumption that the event is emitted only 1 time per emitter (i.e. `emitter.emit('root');` is called only once for any `emitter` instance), then perhaps you can write something that works like jQuery's `$.ready()` event.

In that case, subscribing to `emitter.once('root', function() { ... })` will check whether `'root'` was emitted already, and if so, will invoke the handler anyway. And if `'root'` was not emitted yet, it'll defer to the normal, existing functionality.

That's all I got.

Answer (score 1):

I think this architecture is in trouble, as you're doing sequential work (I/O) that requires definite order of actions but still plan to build app on components that naturally allow non-deterministic order of execution.

What you can do

Include context selector in mediator.on function e.g. in this way

```
mediator.on('http.request > root', function( .. ) { } )
```

Or define it as submediator

```
var submediator = mediator.yield('http.request > root');
submediator.on(function( ... ) {
     emitter.once('root', ... )
});
```

This would trigger the callback only if root was emitted from http.request handler.

Another trickier way is to make background ordering, but it's not feasible with your current one mediator rules them all interface. Implement code so, that each .emit call does not actually send the event, but puts the produced event in list. Each .once puts consume event record in the same list. When all mediator.on callbacks have been executed, walk through the list, sort it by dependency order (e.g. if list has first consume 'root' and then produce 'root' swap them). Then execute consume handlers in order. If you run out of events, stop executing.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, this seems like a very broken architecture for a few reasons:

1. How do you pass around `request` and `response`? It looks like you've got global references to them.
2. If I answer your question, you will turn your server into a pure synchronous function and you'd lose the power of async node.js. (Requests would be queued effectively, and could only start executing once the last request is 100% finished.)

To fix this:

1. Pass `request` & `response` to the `emit()` call as parameters. Now you don't need to force everything to run synchronously anymore, because when the next component handles the event, it will have a reference to the right request & response objects.
2. Learn about other common solutions that don't need a global mediator. Look at the pattern that Connect was based on many Internet-years ago: http://howtonode.org/connect-it <- describes middleware/onion routing

Comment: I don't have global references to request and response, they are emitted on each server request using the mediator. I don't see how turning the server into a synchronous function would solve the issue. Maybe we're not talking about the same thing here?